# Що означає знак § в текстах законів?

Tags: пунктуація

В законодавстві України використовується слово **стаття** щоб вказати де стаття починається. Це слово також має інші функції в текстах законів.

В [текстах законів Естонії](https://www.riigiteataja.ee/en/eli/ee/Riigikogu/act/524012024003/consolide) використовується знак §.

Чи доцільно також почати використовувати § знак замість слова стаття?
На мою думку ці зміни зроблять текст законів легшими для сприйняття.

Оновлення.

Кримінальний процесуальний кодекс використовує символ §.
До прикладу [§ 2. Сторона обвинувачення](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/4651-17#n622).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [§](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0) [Символ параграфа](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84)

**Символ розділу** або **знак розділу** — це друкарський знак для посилань на окремі [пронумеровані розділи документа](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf). Він також може використовуватися при цитуванні розділів правового кодексу.

Проте тексти [Законів України](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/2704-19#Text), які публікуються на державному порталі Верховної Ради, використовують інші означення, а саме **Розділи** і **Статті**. При цитуванні документа позначки на означення його розділів зазвичай зберігають як в оригіналі, щоб уникнути плутанини та невідповідностей.